# Strongest Neighbour question in GeekForGeeks

Tags: c++, arrays, std

Input:
n = 6
arr[] = {1,2,2,3,4,5}
Output: 2 2 3 4 5
Explanation: Maximum of arr[0] and arr[1]
is 2, that of arr[1] and arr[2] is 2, ...
and so on. For last two elements, maximum
is 5.
A standard array problem and I know the right solution to it too but I tried using the `max()` function in the C++ std library and I'm getting this

```
For Input:
6
1 2 2 3 4 5

your output is: 
22345
```

This is how my function looks like

```
void maximumAdjacent(int sizeOfArray, int arr[]){
    
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeOfArray-1; i++) {
        cout << std::max(arr[i+1], arr[i]) << "";
    }
}
```

On submission this answer isn't accepted and I can't seem to figure out why?

Comment: Probably need spaces between the printed numbers.

Comment: It would help to include what the requirement is. Are you saying the expected output is 2 2 3 4 5, or that your output is 2 2 3 4 5?

Comment: the expected output is 2 2 3 4 5

Comment: @user4581301 it was actually a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a dumb answer but it looks like you are missing spaces between the numbers. I see the `""` in your string and you might need a `" "` instead. Without the space, it is one giant number. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah that a dumb mistake on my part. Thanks!

Comment: If an answer helps you, the green check mark is always appreciated.

Comment: "you can accept an answer in 7 minutes" will do it after 7 minutes : )